# Calling a function of a parameter list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript, and was wondering how I would go about calling a function variable. In the following code example, I would like to be able to call the add function of the fileupload control and pass my own data. How would I go about doing this? Thank you.

Here is a butchered version of the blueimp fileupload code that I am trying to call the add() function for.

```
// The UI version extends the file upload widget
// and adds complete user interface interaction:
$.widget('blueimp.fileupload', $.blueimp.fileupload, {
 options: {
  autoUpload: false,
  add: function (e, data) {
  //function stuff
  }

 }
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you call that `add` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to reuse that function, you can supply a reference to `add` instead of a function literal:

```
var myAdd = function (e, data) {
    ...
};

$.widget('blueimp.fileupload', $.blueimp.fileupload, {
    options: {
    autoUpload: false,
    add: myAdd
});
```

Now you can call `myAdd` on your own. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I want. But out of curiosity, is it possible to call the function literal the way it is right now?

Comment: Not the way you have it right now, no. But if you had a reference to the object literal (similar to the way you have a reference to the function). Then you could do something like `options.add(...)`.